# Using Aurelia, how to set a default value for a custom attribute

Tags: aurelia

view

```
<template>
  <div single-value-attrib="${color}"></div>
  <div single-value-attrib.bind="color"></div>
  <input type="text" value.bind="color" />
</template>
```

view-model

```
export class SingleValueAttribCustomAttribute {
  static inject = [Element];
  color = 'orange';
  constructor(element) {

    this.element = element;
    this.element.style.width = this.element.style.height = '100px';
  }

  bind() {
    this.element.style.backgroundColor = this.value;
  }

  valueChanged(newValue, oldValue) {
    this.element.style.backgroundColor = newValue;
  }
}
```

I was expecting that `color='orange';` in the viewModel would map to color on the view thus setting the default color as orange.  Changing the color in the input box works as expected.  I know you can just set `this.value` to a color as your default but I just thought that the binding would work the same way as in the skeleton-nav where the input boxes have default values for firstName and lastName

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, note that `this.color` isn't used anywhere in the code viewmodel, so setting it really doesn't do anything in the code as it exists.

After some playing around, I've determined that your best bet in this specific situation, is going to be to set the background color in the constructor and get rid of the `bind` function. I've create a gist.run here: https://gist.run/?id=a15e0305f082f6ef080364caff2a1ec1

Here is the VM for the custom attribute:

```
export class SingleValueAttribCustomAttribute {
  static inject = [Element];
  defaultColor = 'orange';
  constructor(element) {

    this.element = element;
    this.element.style.width = this.element.style.height = '100px';
    this.element.style.backgroundColor = this.defaultColor; 
  }

  valueChanged(color) {
    if(color.trim() !== '') {
      this.element.style.backgroundColor = color;
    }
  }
}
```

You may want to remove the the check for empty string on `color` in `valueChanged`, depending on your use-case.

Comment: Changing color to value = 'orange' does not work.  Setting this.value='orange' in the constructor also does not work, but it makes sense that it should.  If I change this.value to this.myvalue and set this.myvalue='orange' then it works.

Comment: You know what? You're correct. I'm gonna update the answer to be correct. :-)